# How to determine N of LOOCV

Tags: self-study, cross-validation, predictive-models

In my textbook, it says that LOOCV is where $K=N$, but how do I find the value of $N$?

Is it just $K-1$?

Comment: LOOCV stands for leave one out cross validation. It means that for N observations you fit the model with all but 1 observation and test the model on the observation left  out. This is repeated N-1 times with a different observation left out. It is done so each repetition leaves a different one out.

Answer (score 0):

Leave One Out Cross Validation (as stated by Michael Chernick) is simply a special case of k-Fold Cross Validation where $k=N$ and $N$ is the number of samples in your data set.

If your data set is 10 records (rows), then $N = 10 = k$.

k-Fold Cross Validation is the partitioning of data into k parts, where training occurs on k-1 parts, and testing occurs on the remaining data.

LOOCV is this same process but k=N such as

[image]

Please refer to this lecture for more details!

- YouTube: [StatsLearning Lect7b 110613 from *An Introduction to Statistical Learning*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZAM5OXrktY)